# E-mail known base64 with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, canvas

I have build a website where a users Facebook profile will be viewed in a canvas. The canvas is converted to a PNG, but I would like to email this png file to the user. How can I solve this?

I have build this whole canvas/PNG function with Javascript. Based on a form (like name, postal code etc), filled in by the user himself, the email will be sent with PHP. This makes it difficult for me to also send the base64 within the email. Please help me out.

Here is my code.
JS function to put user info into a canvas and convert it to a PNG

**javascript**

```
function getUserLocation() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        var usr_info = " Je meeste recente locatie is " + response.location.name;

        var c = document.getElementById("privateMe");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        ctx.font = "bold 12px Helvetica";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText(usr_info, 200, 20);
    });
}
```

**html**

```
<img src="#" id="myPrivateImg" name="myPrivateImg">
```

Comment: so you wish to upload that image to your PHP server, and from there to send an email with this image as attachment? if so i think you need to add the PHP code instead

Comment: if you have the png on the server, then just stuff it into a MIME email as an attachment. otherwise you could keep it as base64 and simply use a data uri: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,base64_data_here">`

Comment: Right now I have <img src="the base64 data">.
I would like to send the base64 data within my email. The email is sent with PHP. I have already written a PHP code for sending the email. But I am missing the part for sending the base64 data within the email. 

It doesn't have to be a attachment. Only the base64 url will be fine!